# Laravel 5.5 $redirectTo not changing after 2 modifications

Tags: redirect, routes, laravel-5.5

I'm building a Laravel 5.5 app, I used the default make:Auth for my authetication and I added an admin role (by just checking if in the DB the column is_admin is true) I wanted to modify the login process by changing the route depending if the user is admin or not, I used the code from the documentation therefore commenting the line `protected $redirectTo = '/home';` 
and replacing it with a function

```
public function redirectTo(){
    // Code here
}
```

It worked fine, so I started working on something else, then when I tried to login again I was redirected to `/` automatically, so I tried modifying my code but I would always be redirected to `/` whatever I changed.

I then chose to go back to just `protected $redirectTo = '/home';` and even then I was redirected to `/`, so I stopped working on it for a few hours.

Went back to it (I had turned off my computer) and now I was redirected to `/home`, so I modified it to be redirected to `/` and it worked, but then when I put my function again, it wouldn't work, still always redirected to `/` even if I went back to `protected $redirectTo = '/home';` instead of my function.

So turned off my computer and started again, same thing, it worked at first but after two changes it didn't work anymore. Tried it on another computer, same thing, worked for 2 times and then does not work anymore until I reboot.

For me it looks like a caching issue so I made a little script which does the following

```
#!/bin/bash
php artisan optimize
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:cache
php artisan view:clear
php artisan config:cache
echo "Cache cleared!"
```

but that did not fix the problem, onlly rebooting does.

Anybody got the same problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: So going back through all the commits it seems that commenting
`Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});`
in `routes/web.php` might have been the problem, when I uncommented it it looks like it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: do not comment out

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

in `routes/web.php`